# High Latency between Hazelcast members (using Topic publish/onMessage)

Tags: java, azure, delay, messaging, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast (v3.5.4) Topics for a really simple chat application running on two Azure VMs (Standard D3).

When publishing messages sometimes it takes up to 15 seconds to be received by the other member.
I logged publish and onMessage methods to be clear that hazelcast is causing the delay. 
There is no network delay and the applications and VMs are using nearly zero CPU resources.
What can cause such a delay?

For messaging Topics are used:

```
private ITopic<ChatMessage> eventTopic;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    eventTopic = hazelcastInstance.getTopic("chat-messages");
    eventTopic.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener());
}

public void publishMessage(final ChatMessage chatMessage) {
    log.debug("Publish message: " + chatMessage.toString());
    eventTopic.publish(chatMessage);
}
```

The two azure VMs are in the same region and the latency (Ping) between these two VMs is under 5ms.

Multicast join is disabled, static TcpJoin is used:

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    final Config config = new Config();
    NetworkConfig networkConfig = config.getNetworkConfig();

    networkConfig.setPort(5701);
    networkConfig.setPortAutoIncrement(true);
    networkConfig.setPortCount(3);
    networkConfig.getInterfaces()
        .addInterface("10.0.0.*")
        .setEnabled(true);
    final JoinConfig join = networkConfig.getJoin();
    join.getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
    join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember("10.0.0.1-2").setEnabled(true);

    return HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

Spring Boot 1.3 is used with hazelcast-spring 3.5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for you replies, 
I found the cause of the delay, in my MessageListener I used

```
message.getPublishingMember().getSocketAddress().getHostName()
```

for logging.
On windows machines the getHostName method sometimes takes up to 15 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the cause of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

15 seconds is a lot (like insane). Perhaps the clocks are not in sync of the machines?

Can you change your application so you memberA publishes message to memberB and memberB publishes a response to memberA.

On memberA you measure the RTT (Round Trip Time) and then you divide it by 2 to see how much one message send/receive took. At least then you get rid of any problems with system clocks.

Answer (score 1):

On Azure, there is some concept `Availability Set` and `Virtual Network` for Azure VMs.

The `Availability Set` can help join your VMs into a virtual network to improve communication ability under `Region/Virtual Network` .

You can try to solve the issue by using `Availability Set` and `Virtual Network`, please refer to these documents https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-how-to-configure-availability/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-vnet-arm-pportal/ to do it.

Meanwhile, there is a whitepaper (https://hazelcast.com/resources/whitepaper-best-practices-azure/) you can request a download link for the topic "Hazelcast on Azure: Best Practices for Deployment" on Hazelcast offical resource center.

You can follow the content of the whitepaper to configure the network and mitigate network latency.